# Add CSS hover effect to label under checkbox that alters div

Tags: html, css, checkbox

How to add CSS hover effect to label under input?
I’m trying to find general solution without div IDs.

Live demo can be found on JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/AugerHybrid/8u045Lpc

It should expand/shrink the corresponding div when checkbox is checked.
It should show hover effect to indicate that label is clickable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>checkbox expand div</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      .case {
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
      }
      .case label {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: coral;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .case input {
        text-align: center;
        height: 55px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .project-input {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        display: block;
      }
      .projectcontent {
        max-height: 50px;
        transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #888;
      }
      .case .project-input:checked + .projectcontent {
        max-height: 2000px;
        overflow: visible;
        transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <h1>Expand divs</h1>
      <div class="case">
        <label for="project-input">
          <h2>Click here to expand/shrink this div</h2></label
        >

        <input type="checkbox" class="project-input" title="Expand / Shrink" />

        <div class="projectcontent">
          <p>Lorem ipsum<br />dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>consectetur<br />adipiscing elit.</p>
          <p>sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt.</p>
          <p>ut labore et<br />dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="case">
        <label for="project-input">
          <h2>Click here to expand/shrink this div</h2></label
        >

        <input type="checkbox" class="project-input" title="Expand / Shrink" />

        <div class="projectcontent">
          <p>Lorem ipsum<br />dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>consectetur<br />adipiscing elit.</p>
          <p>sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt.</p>
          <p>ut labore et<br />dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLD'R - add `.case label:hover` role. Hide the input completely (using `clip` for example) and match the label `for` and the input `id` attributes.

**Detailed explanation**

- You can add `:hover` to the label to make the hover effect. **The issue** here is the input appears **on top** of the label so the label doesn't "catch" the hover.
- **The solution** is to hide the input completely. **The issue** clicking on the label now does nothing.
- **The solution** is to match the label `for` and the input `id` attributes so clicking the labels will check / uncheck the input.

https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/jptv3snb/1/